# Finding unused enum members in C

Tags: c, enums

What is the fastest way to find unused enum members?

Commenting values out one by one won't work because I have almost 700 members and want to trim off a few unused ones.

Comment: Write a program creating the `enum` definition source the way you want, and run it as a pre-compilation step from the Makefile? Save the logs of all builds and parse them for the related compilation errors?

Comment: You could write a script which masks an enum, then rebuilds the project, then unmasks the enum if compilations errors are reported, then proceeds to the next enum.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Compilers normally don't tell you about redundant declarations/definitions in your code (with the exception of unused local variables).

Comment: ... or just write a script `grep`ing all the sources for each `enum` value in question?

Comment: Consider dropping all except the ones you know are used.  Recompile, looking for the errors relating to missing enumerations.  Don't do it one by one; get the whole story all at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not aware of any compiler warning, but you could possibly try with [`splint`](http://splint.org/) static analyzer tool. According to its [documentation](http://splint.org/manual/manual.html#completeness) (emphasis mine):

> Splint detects constants, functions, parameters, variables, types,
>   **enumerator members**, and structure or union fields that are declared
>   but never used.

As I checked, it works as intented. Here is example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum Month { JAN, FEB, MAR };

int main()
{
    enum Month m1 = JAN;
    printf("%d\n", m1);
}
```

By running the `splint` command, you will obtain following messages:

```
main.c:3:19: Enum member FEB not used
   A member of an enum type is never used. (Use -enummemuse to inhibit warning)
main.c:3:24: Enum member MAR not used
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that »unused« is a relatively dangerous term here.

```
typedef enum type_t { VALUE_A, VALUE_B, VALUE_C } type_t;

int main() {
    printf("A = %d, ", VALUE_A);
    printf("C = %d", VALUE_C);
    return 0;
}
```

will print `A = 0, C = 2`, but removing the »unused« `VALUE_B` changes the output to `A = 0, C = 1`.

If you persist such values, do arithmetic on it or anything in that area you might end up changing the behavior of your program.

Comment: If you really care about compatibility, you should always explicitly assign values to enumeration tags anyway.

Comment: Of course, but it's still something that can be overlooked relatively easy. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Change the names of all the enums (by, say, adding a `_` before their name). Compile. You'll get a lot of errors because it won't find the previous enum names (obviously). A bit of `grep`-foo and making sure the compiler / build system doesn't stop on the first error - and you'll have a list of all the enums in use!

At least, that's how I'd do it.