# Warning in C compiler about unused enumeration

Tags: c, enums, warnings, static-code-analysis

Is there a warning or some other technique/mechanism/tooling to clean up a C code from unused enumerations?

A solution for C++ code would also be interesting but the question is primarily about C.

Ideally if the solution was to be found based on GNU tools available in common tool chains.

Any compiler or other code analysis tool that is capable of listing unused enumeration members would be interesting to know about.

I am currently using gcc. -Wall is on. No warnings about unused enumeration members appear in the compilation log.

Comment: If you are talking about compile time warnings, i.e. if you are using `gcc`, `-Wall` would be a good start.  Can you edit your post to include what compiler you are actually using?

Comment: -Wall is on, no warnings about unused enumeration members appear in the compilation log.

Comment: Im not aware of any hint/warning that tells you about unused enums. If you use some sort of IDE, you can search for references for each enum. You can rename/comment out all enums, then you get plenty of warnings.

Comment: I wonder if anyone will be able to give the answer: No

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558358/finding-unused-enum-members-in-c

Comment: @lulle Manual processing is not realistic for a larger code base.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to an unknown user in the comments there is an answer. Apparently a tool named [Splint](http://splint.org/manual/manual.html#completeness) is capable of finding unused enumeration members.

Here is a similar question [Finding unused enum members in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558358/finding-unused-enum-members-in-c) asked before, where the aforementioned tool has been analyzed and accepted as a correct answer.